# Linearly dependent columns in dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, data-preprocessing

I need to do the 'cleaning' of the dataset, ie preprocessing. I noticed that I have two columns in the dataset that are totally linearly dependent. Is it okay to delete one, both or am I not allowed to do any one that?

This is a school project and a ‘wild dataset’ where the emphasis is on a data processing. It's necessary to remove excess columns, detect anomalies, correlations between data, etc. Based on the first six parameters we predict the seventh column. If I understood correctly, based on these six parameters I should predict whether it will end up being the letter A, B or C? I mean, it's a matter of classification and not regression? Dataset has about 10.000 rows, here is the first 10, where we immediately see the relationship between the first and fifth columns, and my question is can I remove the fifth column in this case?

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on what you are intending to do with the dataset after pre-processing. Please add this information to the question.

Comment: I edited the post and hopefully the question is clearer now.